# Matplotlib graph annotation legend

Tags: matplotlib, graph, annotations, legend, python-3.6

My code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.annotate('9.15.08: Lehman Brothers', xy=('2008-09-15', 180.00),
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='blue', shrink=0.5),)

ax.annotate('9.29.08: Bailout Vetoed', xy=('2008-09-29', 195.00),
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', shrink=0.5),)

ax.annotate('2.17.09: Stimulus Package', xy=('2009-2-17', 210.00),
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='green', shrink=0.5),)

ax.annotate('3.17.08: Bear Stearns Buyout', xy=('2008-3-17', 225.00),
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='yellow', shrink=0.5),)

plt.plot(date, aal_price, color="blue", linewidth=1, label="American Airlines")
plt.plot(date, aapl_price, color="black", linewidth=1, label="Apple")
plt.plot(date, gs_price, color="red", linewidth=1, label="Goldman Sachs")
plt.plot(date, hd_price, color="purple", linewidth=1, label="Home Depot")
plt.plot(date, ibm_price, color="green", linewidth=1, label="IBM")
plt.plot(date, jnj_price, color="yellow", linewidth=1, label="Johnson & Johnson")
plt.plot(date, pg_price, color="orange", linewidth=1, label="Proctor & Gamble")
plt.plot(date, wmt_price, color="cyan", linewidth=1, label="Wal-Mart")
plt.plot(date, xom_price, color="pink", linewidth=1, label="Exxon Mobil")


plt.legend(loc=2, shadow=bool)
plt.title("Stock Market Analysis: 2008 Stock Market Crash")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("(Stock Price)")
```

renders this graph:

[image]

I want to create an additional legend for the triangular annotations.

I'm attempting to learn but knowing what to try, or even how to search for answers is difficult.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called using a "proxy artist" to populate the legend. It is described in the matplotlib documentation's [Legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html?highlight=legend%20guide#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists), or in the many questions about it on this site, see the link in my other comment above

Comment: Thanks Diziet. Sorry if I was unclear...pretty new to this.

Comment: No worries @Mark. I was just trying to give you pointers on where to look for more information. If you have a specific question implementing the legend, feel free to ask a new question